# Webscraping with selenium, page don't load

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've created a script in Python to do some webscraping and everything was running smooth on my computer. A few days ago, I got a new computer, and when I run the script the website doesn't load. I mean, Google Chrome opens a new window but the website doesn't load. All I get is a blank page.

I know that I have different versions of Chrome in both computers (v72 and v80 in the new one), so I already download the Chromedriver that is compatible with v80. If I change the name of the website, it loads the page. Also, I have a couple more webscraping scripts that runs perfectly.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from datetime import date, timedelta

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import sys
sys._enablelegacywindowsfsencoding()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"\my_path\",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
  "credentials_enable_service": False,
  "profile.password_manager_enabled": False
})

options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation']) 
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")


wdriver = webdriver.Chrome("my_path\\chromedriver80.exe", options=options)

#open
wdriver.get ("https://hub.checkout.com/login")
```

After the last line, all I got is a blank window as you can see below.
[image]

Can you help me??

Comment: I faced a similar situation for a particular website. However, launching it in incognito solved it for me. Could you try adding this parameter?
options.add_argument("--incognito")

Comment: @PrakharJhudele thank you for trying but it doesn't load the website anyway

Comment: Did you checked the devtools? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Jonah nope, no errors or warnings

Comment: Try loading it without the options, just to make sure that those are not the issue.